# Copying dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary of lists containing tuples. I wanted to create a copy of the dictionary and edit only one of the copies. Below are four methods of copying dictionaries that usually work for me:

```
import copy

dicta = {'A':[(1,1)]}
dictb = dicta.copy()
dictc = dict(dicta)
dictd = dict((k,v) for k,v in dicta.items())
dicte = copy.deepcopy(dicta)
```

If you try to change dicta:

```
dicta['A'][0] = [(9,9)]
```

You will find that each copy still points to the same dictionary as dicta, except for the copy created via `copy.deepcopy`. This happens despite `dicta is dictX` returning `False` for all of the copies.

What's going on here?

Comment: What does `dicta["A"] is dictX["A"]` return?

Comment: Note that if you don't want the new contents of `dicta['A']` to be a _nested_ list then the other copy techniques can be used if you do   `dicta['A'] = [(9,9)]`. Of course, they won't work if you do `dicta['A'][0] = (9,9)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dictb` through `dictd` are "shallow copies" of `dicta`. This means they are indeed new dictionaries (that's why they're not the same as `dicta`), but their contents are the same object. Look here:

```
>>> dicta is dictb
False
>>> dicta['A'] is dictb['A']
True
>>> dicta['A'] is dicte['A']
False
```

Only the deepcopy command goes in and makes copies of the **contents** of the things it copies, recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Only `copy.deepcopy()` copies the dictionary recursively, that's why only it works. Other methods don't go recursively through all the dictionary and keep links to all the same lists (or any objects stored in the dictionary), but they still return not the same dictionary (that's why `dicta is dictX` is returning `False` for all of the copies). E.g. you can try deleting some of the entries in a copy and the corresponding entries won't be deleted in the original.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html

Answer (score 1):

You just copied the dictionary, but not things in it. So you did make a new dictionary, but it pointed to the same list.

Answer (score 0):

if you will try `dicta == dictX` it will returns `true` for all except the copy created via `copy.deepcopy`

Its because `is` checks if two variables point to the same object.Here when you create a copy the dictionary they point to different dictionary.

Check this

```
>>>id(dicta)
>>>id(dictb)
>>>id(dicta['A'])
>>>id(dictb['A'])
```

This will clear your doubt.

Comment: `a is a.copy()` will return `False`. Try it in IDLE.

Comment: `a is a.copy()`  returns `True` only for immutable types. For immutable types the `id` of both `a` and `a.copy()` are same. For list it will return `False`.